# what is a way to filter csv data by date and time without using pandas, instead using if statements and lists?

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a csv of support tickets for the whole year.
first column is ticket number, next one is date created, employee name, subject, status etc.
dates are written in this format: 3/25/2021 13:55
I know how to use basic lists of lists and dictionaries in python, and basic if statements, but I don't know how to make a list that contains only tickets summited on the 24th march. I might want to filter by month with a bigger data selection and make a list of all tickets submitted in february, but I dont know how to filter them.
I dont want to use pandas as thats too confusing for me, Im a beginner.
Can I use datetime to do it, or some other way?

'''

```
opened_file = open(r'Y:\Eric_IT\all tickets this year Tickets - 20210325.csv')

from csv import reader
import datetime

read_file = reader(opened_file)
all_data = list(read_file)

print('These are headers:')
headers = all_data[0]
print(headers)
ticket_data = all_data[1:]
print('Number of tickets this year:')
print(len(ticket_data))

jan = 0
feb = 0
mar = 0

for each in ticket_data:
    if each[1] = ???    # [1] is the date field in my excel, and I want to take all february entries and put them in my feb list.
```

'''
[image: data]

Comment: This reads like multiple questions in one - can you boil it down a bit? Do you have an understanding of how to read and parse the `csv`, to a `dict` for example? Also, it's kind of hard to suggest a helpful solution without knowing how your data looks like - can you add a couple of lines from that?

Comment: hello. I updated my question with a sample of my data. Basically our ticket system dashboard doesnt show the metrics our boss wants to see. How many tickets in the last month, how many were resolved etc. so Im hoping to build a weekly report in python that shows the target information without giving the poor guy a giant csv of information he doesnt want.

Comment: besides @Aaron's answer which I think might clarify things for you, make sure to get the basics right. E.g. if you open a file, close it. Don't leave it hanging there. Even better, use the `with` statement, see e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/). If you want to dig deeper, write your own csv parser. It's not that difficult. But the task you describe is more high-level than that. So once you got the basics, have a look at pandas. It offers good tools for your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: pandas]

This idiot right here did it!! Look guys! I followed an pandas for beginners tutorial and I pandas-ed the columns I wanted to dates! Now I can count and sort stuff. When I finish celebrating, I will go learn how to do that. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Please edit your answer and paste the code rather than an image of code. Images are not searchable, cannot be read by screen readers for those with vision disability, and cannot be indexed and searched by those who may have the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the dates to datetime objects and then you can use attributes like the month or day to filter. I'd prefer myself to use a list comprehension. The error you mention in the comment means that it didn't convert to a datetime object.
import datetime as dt

```
jan = [dt.datetime.strptime(item[1], '%Y-%m-%d') for item in ticket_data if dt.datetime.strptime(item[1], '%m') == 1]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
https://www.kite.com/python/examples/2830/datetime-get-the-year,-month,-and-day-of-a-%60date%60

Comment: I tried that, but it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\IT\Ticket Summary.py", line 16, in <module>
    jan = [item[1] for item in ticket_data if item[1].dt.month == 1]
  File "Y:\IT\Ticket Summary.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    jan = [item[1] for item in ticket_data if item[1].dt.month == 1]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dt'

Answer (score 1):

You already have all your data as a list of lists, and separate from the headers which is the first step. The second step is sorting / filtering the data based on some criterion.

Say for example you want to sort based on date. Naturally we'll be using python's built-in [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function (as long as we're staying away from libraries like pandas etc...). When you have complex data, it's usually necessary to pass a "key" function to the `sort` function in order to tell it how you want your data sorted. In this case we need to tell it we want to sort based on the "date" column, so we will need to tell it the sort value is the second element of each row, and that it should convert the string into a numerical date which can then be compared as numbers (think of "key" functions as taking in arbitrary data like an entire row of the csv, and returning a numerical value with which to sort based on. It doesn't have to strictly output a numerical value, but it's often easier if it does and dates can be interpreted as numbers.)

```
def sort_date(row):
    date_string = row[1] #date was second column
    dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") #you'll need to change the format string to match the format excel spits out into the csv for you
    return dt

ticket_data.sort(sort_date) #sort ticket_data in-place by date
```

Sorting on "ticket number" would be even easier, as it already is in a numeric format (though we will probably have to convert it from a string.)

```
def sort_ticket_no(row):
    return int(row[0])
ticket_data.sort(sort_ticket_no) #sort ticket_data in-place by ticket number
```

Selecting data based on conditions like from the "source" column can be done in a number of ways, but I will show an example of how I might do it.

First I would get all possible "sources" by making a dictionary which will have entries for each "source" type which is a list of rows. Then I would iterate over all your rows, and append each row to the appropriate category:

```
grouped_by_source = {}

for row in ticket_data:
    if row[8] in grouped_by_source: #8th column check if there's an entry yet we can append to
        grouped_by_source[row[8]].append(row)
    else:
        grouped_by_source[row[8]] = [row] #create a new list containing our row if it's the first from a given "source"
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats way too complex for me to understand. I think Ill give up at this point, but thank you for such a detail answered.